# Openshift Node.js cartridge has python?

Tags: openshift

I am using openshift to host a Node.js application. It seems to be working fine. However, I am trying to install new node modules that require python. Does a node.js cartridge come with python too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes

Long answer:  The node.js cartridge has access to all other languages that OpenShift Online supports, including, but not limited to, Python, Ruby, PHP, Java, C++, etc.  Though, it is probably using the system version, which is most likely a lower version that your module might need to build.  You can verify this, and the version, by sshing into your application and running the command `python --version`  which will probably output `Python 2.6.6`.  You should look up the python version dependency for the module that you are trying to install.  You should also keep in mind that the Node.js cartridge is not setup specifically to support Python, so it's also possible that something else is missing like a virtualenv.  You should try adding more information to your question such as any errors that you are getting, along with what module you are trying to install, and possibly a link to a copy of your package.json so that others can try and troubleshoot the issue.